# Are stereo speakers suitable substitutes for studio/rehearsal monitor? What amps/preapms are required?

Tags: amplifiers, speakers, homerecording, pre-amp

first time posting.
I have an old JVC player, model: MX-V508T. It has two unit, a CD/AMP/DECK TUNER UNIT and a Speaker unit. The CD/AMP/DECK TUNER UNIT is getting beyond repair. So, I want to dispose it and use the speakers for group practicing and starting a home studio for recording.
My intended inputs for practice/rehearsal include synthesizer keyboard, a bass, 1-2 guitars, acoustic and/or electric, and 1-3 vocals.
I intend to get a 8/10 channel analog mixer with USB interface which will be able to serve both practice and recording.

Question 1: Are the speakers suitable substitutes for studio/recording monitor and as full range practice monitors?

Question 2: if applicable, what type amp/preamp is required for connecting the speakers with the mixer output?

**CD/AMP/DECK TUNER UNIT Amplifier section SPECIFICATIONS**
*CA-V508T*

Output Power (IEC 268-3/DIN): 27 watts per channel, min. RMS, both channels driven, into 6 ohms at 1 kHz, with no more than 0.9% total harmonic distortion.

Input Sensitivity/Impedance (1 kHz): 300 mV/50 kohms

AUX: 300 mV/500 kohms

MIC 1: 3 mV/4.7 kohms

MIC 2: 3 mV/4.7 kohms

Speaker terminals: 6 - 16 ohms

Video out (composite): 1.0Vp-p (75 )

**Speaker Specifications**

*SP-V608*

Speaker: 3-way, 3-speaker bass-reflex type (Magnetically-shielded type)

Tweeter: 2 cm (13/16 inches) dome 1

Mid range: 5 cm (2 inches) cone 1

Woofer: 16 cm (6-5/16 inches) cone 1

Power Handling Capacity: 80 Watts

Impedance: 6 ohms

Frequency Range: 46 - 20,000 Hz

Sound Pressure Level: 87 dB/w • m

**Power Specifications**

Power Requirements: AC 110/127/220/230-240 V, adjustable with the voltage selector, 50/60 Hz

Power Consumption: 85 watts

Max. Power Comsumption: 12 watts (in standby mode), 185 watts (Taiwan only)

For Additional info for the player, [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/83480/Jvc-Mx-V508t.html?page=47#manual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of music you wish to play and how loud you wish to play it, it may work just fine but you'll need to test it out in you're own situation. I've had acoustic jams at the house that my little 3o watt stereo handled just fine, but I only used it for vocals. I seriously doubt it could have handled instrumentation and vocals. I was also careful not to push anything into distortion and I wasn't trying to blast out the neighbors. My set-up had a small mixer plugged into the auxiliary inputs on my stereo, simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the JVC with something similar and limp along.  But I think you'd blow up the speakers pretty soon if used as recording monitors.   And as a practice PA system - forget it!  Sorry.

Comment: Blow them up using the as recording monitors? How? The volumes used may well not even be as great as when listening to music. However, as a practice p.a., totally agree!